# In python pytest, How do I start a new runtime for each test function?

Tags: python, pytest, singleton

I have a singlton function that I want to test as below:

```
import abc


class SingletonABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonABCMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls._instances[cls]
        else:
            raise Exception("This is a singleton. no more than one instance of it can exist")


class Cabc(abc.ABC, metaclass=SingletonABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self): pass


class C(Cabc):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"initializing with {a}")
        self._a = a

    def foo(self):
        return self._a


def test_c_first():
    ins = C(1)
    assert ins.foo() == 1


def test_c_second():
    # this test fails but I don't want it to fail. 
    # I want to be able to have a fresh session to be able to create a fresh instance from the class C
    ins = C(2)
    assert ins.foo() == 2
```

The second time I am testing it I want it to be in a new runtime so that I can create a new instance.

Right now the second test fails. The desired behavior is both tests pass.

one solution is removing the instances at the end of first test

```
def test_c_first():
    ins = C(1)
    assert ins.foo() == 1
    C._instances = {}
```

But I prefer not to do this and keep the tests closer to real situations. I am looking for starting a new runtime somehow

How do I do this?

context:
My singleton is a memory database client that I want to initialize in each test and test my fastapi application

Comment: You could make your tests into classes derived from `TestCase` and then add a `def tearDown(self): C._instances = {}` method to clear the singleton.

Comment: it is still doing `C._instances = {}`. I want to avoid this. I want a new runtime. is it possible?

Comment: What is the downside of doing `C._instances = {}`? Surely that is faster than spinning up a new runtime.

Comment: dev-prod parity. I want my test to look like reality as much as possible

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by using a `tearDown()`. It leaves each test looking just like your examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in Python that allows you to do exactly what you're asking: subinterpreters. Unfortunately, it's only available through the [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#sub-interpreter-support). There is a proposal, [PEP 554](https://peps.python.org/pep-0554/), to add a module for accessing the feature from Python, but it's not available (or even decided?) yet.

Another solution is to use the [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module from the standard library to create another module instance and defeat the singleton pattern:

```
def test_c_multiple_instances():
    C = runpy.run_path(__file__)["C"]
    c1 = C(1)

    C = runpy.run_path(__file__)["C"]
    c2 = C(2)

    assert c1.foo() == 1
    assert c2.foo() == 2
```

And of course, as you mentioned yourself, you could also simply reset the state of the singleton.

But ultimately, it might be better to rework the problem. As you say in your exception message, a singleton tries to make sure that no more than one instance can exist. But for testing you want to make new instances, which is also what you are trying to prevent, so any solution will depend on finding a flaw in the singleton implementation and defeating it. The requirements are somewhat contradictory.

This is part of why the singleton pattern is widely considered a bad idea. It makes testing difficult and doesn't add much value. What exactly is it guaranteeing? One instance per *what* exactly – per machine, per logged in user, per process, per instance of the interpreter, per sub-interpreter, per Java classloader? Is that a useful guarantee?

So the solution I would suggest is to make it a normal class an create whatever number of instances you need in any given context. If you need a single instance, you can make it a module-level (i.e. global) variable, as Python modules are already singletons.